# How to determine the exact number of nodes of the fully-connected-layer after Convolutional Layers?

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
            
    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
    
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9*9*32, 200)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(200, 50)
    self.output = nn.Linear(50, 10)
```

RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [20 x 2048], m2: [2592 x 200] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1524584710464/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:2033

I applied the formula W’ = ((W-F+2P)/S)+1 I ended up with 9 pixels per side instead of 8:

W’ = ((W-F+2P)/S)+1 = ((32-2+2)/1)+1=31

Max Pool W’ = 31/2 = 15.5 —>16

W’’ = ((W-F+2P)/S)+1 = ((16-2+2)/1)+1=17

Max Pool W’ = 17/2 = 8.5 —> 9

9*9*32 = 2592

8*8*32 = 2048

I cannot understand why the nu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculation for the output size is incorrect, in your calculation of the output size of the first max pooling layer you are rounding the result up to 16. However, as the [pytorch documentation shows](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html) the result is floored, which in this case would give an output size of 15. Continuing with the calculations steps after it will leave you with a size of 8.